# iOs - hide buttons when entering edit mode

Tags: ios4, uitableview

I have an UITableView that contains 2 buttons for each UITableviewCell.
How to hide the buttons when the UITableview is in edit mode?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to subclass UITableViewCell and add the buttons as properties, then set their `hidden`property to YES:

```
@interface CustomCell: UITableViewCell
{
    UIButton *btn1;
    UIButton *btn2;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIButon *btn1;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIButon *btn2;

- (void)showButtons;
- (void)hideButtons;

@end

@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize btn1, btn2;

- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSStrig *)reuseId
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseidentifier:reuseId]))
    {
        btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        // etc. etc.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) hideButtons
{
    self.btn1.hidden = YES;
    self.btn2.hidden = YES;
}

- (void) showButtons
{
    self.btn1.hidden = NO;
    self.btn2.hidden = NO;
}

@end
```

And in your UITableViewDelegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [(CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] hideButtons];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [(CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] showButtons];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3, it works when I update a single cell, but do you an idea how to apply this method when all the cells are in edit mode? (means when the "minus" button appears on all rows?)

Comment: I found this for hiding the buttons:

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [(CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] hideButtons];

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
}

But don't know show them back when I leave the edit mode.

Comment: Anyway, this method is NOT called when you update the cells. It's called among the other delegate methods.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to update this thread with a much simpler solution. In order to hide specific elements in a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, simply override one method for `UITableViewCell` (implementation in Swift):

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    // Customize the cell's elements for both edit & non-edit mode
    self.button1.hidden = editing
    self.button2.hidden = editing
}
```

This will be called automatically for each cell after you call the parent `UITableView`'s `-setEditing:animated:` method.